# Importing demo content from plugin

Tags: import

I need to create "Import demo content" button on frontend, when the user clicks it, import demo content including attachments. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Import XML somehow? Import db? Create all the content in the plugin manually?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at WordPoress's import/export and wrx files?

Comment: I need to do this from code...

Comment: Yes you would write code like the kind you find in the functions above or by looking at a wrx file to see how the format is structured....